# is this relation in third normal form?

Tags: database, relational-database, normalization

I was wondering, is the following relation in 3rd normal form ?

```
USER (username:String PrimaryKey, 
      userType:String, 
      fname:String,
      lname:String, 
      dateOfBirth:TimeStamp)
```

and userType can be one of the following values

1. Guest
2. Registered User
3. Referred User

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

If the FD's that apply in your database are

{username} -> {userType, fname, lname, dateOfBirth}

then your design is even in 5NF.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any transitive dependencies between non-key attributes... so it's 3NF compliant.

Answer (score 0):

but of course be very careful when considering the user name as the primary key of the user table. It usually does not work...

Comment: Would you really want to allow duplicate usernames? Assuming @Ali wants to guarantee that no two users can have the same username then it seems that username "works" as a key.